# load json HashMap into javascript Object

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary, hashmap, lodash

Hi I have an `HashMap<String, List<MyObject>>` sent in Json from my Java App like this:

```
{
    "316N": [
        {
            "userCreate": null,
            "dateCreate": null,
            "userMaj": null,
            "dateMaj": null,
            "archive": false,
            "nomComposant": "cob",
            "versionComposant": 2,
            "checksumSrcComposant": "1235",
            "checksumBinComposant": "1235"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to simply parse this json object into a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) or sthg else from a cool javascript lib that I do not know (did not find that in [lodash](https://lodash.com/)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `Map` constructor taking output of `Object.entries`

```
new Map( Object.entries( obj ) )
```

**Demo**

```js
var obj = {
    "316N": [
        {
            "userCreate": null,
            "dateCreate": null,
            "userMaj": null,
            "dateMaj": null,
            "archive": false,
            "nomComposant": "cob",
            "versionComposant": 2,
            "checksumSrcComposant": "1235",
            "checksumBinComposant": "1235"
        }
    ]
};
var output =  new Map( Object.entries( obj ) );

var mapIter = output.entries();

console.log(mapIter.next().value);
```

Comment: Nice, I was using Object.keys to iterate and then obj[prop]. Using a Map is cleaner, thx